# How to show scrollbar in SliverList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I'm using SliverAppBar and SliverList as main containers in my app. 
When I try to wrap SliverList in Scrollbar widget, I get an error, and when I wrap whole CustomScrollView in Scrollbar, it overlaps SliverAppBar. 
So how can I show scrollbar indicator only in my SliverList? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code so far? could you show your progress? You can build one yourself using a stack widget: https://medium.com/flutter-community/creating-draggable-scrollbar-in-flutter-a0ae8cf3143b

Comment: As I see, in your example simple AppBar was used, not a SliverAppBar.

Answer (score 5):

Check out @JLarana's answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62938436/10647220

But basically what you need to do is:

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
...
body: PrimaryScrollController(
    controller: _scrollController,
        child: CupertinoScrollbar(
            child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers:[
                    your slivers code here
                 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly... as of Flutter 1.12 released in Dec 2019, I think this issue is currently tracked under

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13253

I'm not aware of a easy solution for this(maybe `NestedScrollView` will solve your problem, but it has some subtle fidelity [issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31009) so I don't want to use).